# Why does my Macbook Pro think my headphones have a microphone?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have a 2016 Macbook Pro running Mojave. Whenever I plug in my headphones (just headphones with no mic), my mac disables its internal mic. This means that my end doesn't capture audio during calls. If I unplug the headphones just a tiny bit, sometimes I can get my mac to capture audio while still getting audio to play through my headphones. How can I solve this problem and use my headphones while using the Mac's internal mic?

This is the plug from my headphones, standard 3-pole connector. Nothing about it suggests that there is a polarity dedicated to a microphone signal.
[image: headphone connector]